# In Regular Expression how to add Special Character's

Tags: vb6

I have regular expression like this:

`regularExp = "^[-]{0,1}([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[\s]){0," & decNum & "}\.$"`

Here I need to add all Special Character's, like `~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?[]\;',./` in VB6.0

Comment: including space also.

Comment: Please see if my code works. Have added code for space

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like [POSIX bracket extensions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) and a special character class which matches all punctuation characters without listing them explicitly.

Unfortunately you are out of luck, since the Regular Expressions available in Visual Basic 6 are provided by the same [VBScript RegExp engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) which was available in IE 5.5. That engine was not updated in 15 years, so [many features are missing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html).

Having said that, your only option is to "handpick" each and every character you want to match and put them in a character class, like this

```
[~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?[\]\\;',./]
```

Fortunately you don't have to escape all special characters within character classes, only the ones which confuse the parser. (Namely `\`, `^`, `-` and `]`)

Comment: Now i changed like this, regularExp = "^.{0," & decNum & "}$" it's accept all the values. Thanks all..

Answer (score 0):

you can use

^[a-zA-Z._^%$#!~@,-]  as  referance and add more special characters which you want to allow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add special characters as below

```
[^%$#!~@()*\s]
```